# Change php code to fit my requirements

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this line I need to replace/edit to fit my needs. This code is extracting first name and last name from wordpress database:

```
'<strong>' . get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $freelancer ) . '</strong>',
```

What I need is to show on website only first name and initial of the last name.

I have used bellow code in other context and working fine but I don't know how to adapt it to above code:

```
<?php
$first_name = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $freelancer );
 $last_name = substr( get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $freelancer ), 0, 1 ) . '.';
$display_name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
echo $display_name;
?>
```

So my second code is working perfect but I need to replace first code with proper code to get the same result , I don't know how, anyway this is more of context code I need to alter:

```
$message = sprintf( __( '%s cancelled his project %s', ET_DOMAIN ),
                '<strong>' . get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $freelancer ) . '</strong>',
                '<strong>' . get_the_title( $project ) . '</strong>'
            );
```

Comment: And what is the result of your current code?

Comment: Result is First Name and Last Name while I need it first name and last name initial, i.e. John David should become John D.

Comment: The code looks legit for me, pls check the encoding. However, if you want to be extra safe, you should go with `mb_substr($your_string, 0, 1, 'utf-8')` so you don't truncate a multibyte string. Are you sure btw that these meta strings contain exact first and last name? It seems that `first_name` actually contains both names while `last name` is empty. That's why probably you get such a result. Make simple `echo` of both `get_the_author_meta()` strings before anything.

Comment: No, my issue is that I don't have the skills to adapt the working code to my line '<strong>' . get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $freelancer ) . '</strong>',

Comment: well, what's the problem to do `'<strong>' . $display_name . '</strong>'` after your code snippet?

Comment: Check update with more code, page won't load if like this:$first_name = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $freelancer );
 $last_name = substr( get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $freelancer ), 0, 1 ) . '.';
$display_name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name; '<strong>' . $display_name . '</strong>'

Comment: You need to start by checking what the result of `get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $freelancer )` is. You are making statements that just don't add up. You claim that the result of your "bellow code in other context and working fine" is FirstName LastName i.e. "John David". But even if the last name bit was empty, there would still be a period at the end. Don't tell us what's happening in other unrelated projects. Tell us what's happening _here_. Run the code you're showing us at tell us what the _actual_ result is.

Comment: You just need to add `echo` before `'<strong>' . $display_name . '</strong>'`

Comment: Thanks Peter HvD, that solved the problem.